# Calculate BMI JavaScript switch

Tags: javascript

I am doing  a standard task with codewares: Write function bmi that calculates body mass index (bmi = weight / height2).

Here is my solution:

```js
function bmi(weight, height) {
  let bmi = weight / (height ** 2)

  if (bmi <= 18.5) {

    return "Underweight";
  } else if (bmi <= 25.0) {

    return "Normal"
  } else if (bmi <= 30.0) {

    return "Overweight"
  } else if (bmi > 30) {
    return "Obese"
  }
}

console.log(bmi(80, 1.80))
```

I have a question: is it possible to solve this problem with the help of a switch?  Because I tried it in different ways and in the console I have `undefined`:

```js
function bmi(weight, height) {

  let bmi = weight / (height ** 2)

  let c = "Normal"

  switch (bmi) {
    case "Underweight":
      bmi <= 18.5;
      break;

    case "Normal":
      bmi <= 25.0;
      break;

    case "Overweight":
      bmi <= 30.0;
      break;

    default:
      return;
  }
}
console.log(bmi(80, 1.80))
```

Comment: switch is like `if` it compares the `switch (x)` expression with the value expression. you can't reverse that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *(Thanks to [user derpirscher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776927/derpirscher) for pointing out I had   provided a completely incorrect answer.  I've updated a corrected answer below.)*

Unfortunately this syntax for [`switch` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), where your case is a complex comparison against the expression, is not supported in JS.  Cases are simply checked against the expression for a simple match.  While one *could* do something like this:

```js
function bmi(weight, height) {

  let bmi = weight / (height ** 2)

  let c = "Normal"

  switch (true) {
    case bmi <= 18.5:
      c = "Underweight";
      break;

    case bmi <= 25.0:
      c = "Normal";
      break;

    case bmi <= 30.0:
    
      c = "Overweight";
      break;

    default:
      c = "Obese"

  }
  return c;
}

console.log(bmi(8, 1.80))
console.log(bmi(80, 1.80))
console.log(bmi(800, 1.80))
```

It is using the `switch` for a case different than its intended purpose.
This is not necessarily a readable or expressive way of writing this-- I think your original approach with the `if...else` is probably preferable to a `switch`-based approach.

Comment: @alenalove - glad this helped-- good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: Since when are such conditions supported? In my browser this snippet always returns "normal" no matter of what values for height or weight i put in ... And it doesn't seem to enter any of the cases

Comment: The correct way of doing this would be to `switch(true)` instead of `switch(bmi)` and also add a `default:` case  to be matched when `bmi >  30`

Comment: @derpirscher - thank you so much for the sanity check on my original answer-- it was completely incorrect. I got sloppy rushed in an answer, which is a bad habit to be in on a Q&A site. I've since updated it with a proper answer based on your feedback.